# How to plot bar plot for factor variales using lapply in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, bar-chart, lapply

I write a function that create geom_bar for every factor variable. Bars show median price of every category.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)
bar_price<-function(var,color=mycol){
  ggplot(train,aes(fct_reorder(var,SalePrice, .desc = TRUE), SalePrice, fill=var))+
      stat_summary(aes(y = SalePrice), fun = "median", geom = "bar")+
      geom_hline(yintercept = median(train$SalePrice), color="red")+
      scale_fill_manual(values = rep(color,  15))+
      geom_label(stat = "count", aes(label = ..count.., y = ..count..), fill="white")+
      ylab("SalePrice")+
      xlab(paste(substitute(var))[3])+
      theme_bw()+
      theme(legend.position = "none")
} 
bar_price(train$MSSubClass , "#202040")
```

[image]

Function bar_price works well. But if I try to make lapply for factor variables, I have an error:
Error: fct_reorder(var, SalePrice, .desc = TRUE) :   length(f) == length(.x) не TRUE

```
factors <- sapply(train, function(x) is.factor(x))
factors_only<- train[,factors]
temp <- lapply(names(factors_only), bar_price)
print(temp[[1]])
```

It's my dataset https://drive.google.com/file/d/1el-gAgA93EbYnM6VnDqzhT5c5uWsnKvq/view?usp=sharing

**How can I solve this problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are running this line :

```
bar_price(train$MSSubClass , "#202040")
```

Notice that `train$MSSubClass` are the values of the column and not the name.

In your `lapply` command you are passing column names to `bar_price` function.

```
temp <- lapply(names(factors_only), bar_price)
```

Instead you should pass column values here as well. Also you did not pass `color` argument.

So try :

```
temp <- lapply(factors_only, bar_price, "#202040")
```

---

To get correct column names on x-axis I would suggest to change the function slightly to this :

```
library(forcats)
library(ggplot2)
library(rlang)

bar_price <- function(data, var,color=mycol){
    ggplot(data,aes(fct_reorder(!!sym(var),SalePrice, .desc = TRUE), 
                    SalePrice, fill = !!sym(var))) +
      stat_summary(aes(y = SalePrice), fun = "median", geom = "bar")+
      geom_hline(yintercept = median(data$SalePrice), color="red")+
      scale_fill_manual(values = rep(color,  15))+
      geom_label(stat = "count", aes(label = ..count.., y = ..count..), 
                fill="white")+
      ylab("SalePrice")+
      xlab(var)+
      theme_bw()+
      theme(legend.position = "none")
}
```

You can then run this as :

```
temp <- lapply(names(factors_only), bar_price, data = train, "#202040")
```

Comment: Thank you! But now name of xaxis is "i", I want to have name of xaxis like a factor variable. What should I do?)